# Command whenever an item in a tablelist is selected in tcl?

Tags: tcl

I have a tablelist and I wanted to show the infos of the current selected item somewhere. Just like synaptic's (pic)

Here is my tablelist:

```
tablelist::tablelist .t.frm.lbf.mlb -selectmode multiple -columns {0 "File" 0 "Name" 0 "Version" 0 "Archtectures" 0 "Summary" 0 "Type"} \
-stretch all -background white -width 57 -xscroll {.t.frm.lbf.h set} -yscroll {.t.frm.lbf.v set}  -showseparators true
```

So whenever a row is clicked (selected) it shows the info

[image]

I was unable to find how to bind a command to an item click(selection).

Comment: I cannot test it right now, but you can look into [this](http://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelistWidget.html#body_bindings), more especially `bind [.tbl bodytag] <Button-1> { ... }` then you either define your command here or create a `proc` which will be called with this bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comment, you can use the bind with `[.tbl bodytag]` to trigger a function when there is a click in your tablelist body. For your example:

```
bind [.t.frm.lbf.mlb bodytag] <Button-1> {
    lassign [tablelist::convEventFields %W %x %y] w x y
    lassign [split [$w containingcell $x $y] ,] row col
    tk_messageBox -title Info -message "This is $row,$col"
}
```

Will display a message box saying which table cell is being clicked. From the tablecell, you can get the tablerow `$row`. From the tablerow, you can get the cell contents of any cell on that row.

For example in the picture, clicking anywhere on the first row would give `$row` a value of 0. You can get the package name by calling something like:

```
set pkgName [lindex [lindex [.t.frm.lbf.mlb rowconfigure $row -text] 4] 2]
```

Which would get you the value `openoffice.org-calc` which you can then use to get whatever information you want to display in a different widget.

`[.t.frm.lbf.mlb rowconfigure $row -text]` gives all the text settings from row `$row`.

`[lindex [.t.frm.lbf.mlb rowconfigure $row -text] 4]` gives the text values from that row only in a tcl list.

`[lindex [lindex [.t.frm.lbf.mlb rowconfigure $row -text] 4] 2]` then gives the text value from the 3rd column (index 2).

Answer (score 3):

Bind a script to the tablelist widget's `<<TablelistSelect>>` virtual event and use `.tablelist curselection` in the event handler to retrieve the selected indices. Be sure to give your columns a -name attribute to make it easy to address the cells even if the user changes the column order:

```
.t.frm.lbf.mlb columnconfigure 0 -name file

bind .t.frm.lbf.mlb <<TablelistSelect>> [list packageSelected %W]

proc packageSelected {w} {
    # -selecttype row is the default
    foreach row [$w curselection] {
        puts [format "Package file %s selected" [$w getcells $row,file]]
    }
}
```